# UI-solution for iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, user-experience

I hope that this kind of question is welcome here (found user-interface in the tags). **If not, please excuse me !**

I have a TableViewController on top of the workflow:

[image]

In my setup, this controller is use to update/add rows:

> SetupViewController

[image]

When the image on the right is tapped, a collection-view is shown and you have to select a *new* image:

[image]

I hope you can give me hints on how to proceed (perhaps with some code-snippet)

**How can I "mark" the images in the SetupViewController** on the right, so that the user recognizes, that he/she should tap on image to select another one (i.e the question mark when adding a record) ?

Comment: This question may receive better answers on [User Experience Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In addition to being on the wrong site, you have also tagged this question with Swift and Xcode. Your question has NOTHING to do with either - please remove these tags.

Comment: @Daniel Storm ok i moved to  User Experience Stack Exchange with this question. THX for thetip!

Comment: @Robotic Cat: your comment is ok, i accept this. But i think, this question is right with this tags anyway but on the wrong site... ;-) But i asked for this, cause i don´t know it better! Daniel Storms comment is mor constructive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would be to either have the image be a + (plus sign) or have the image be an image with the text "add image" on it. Those two are the easiest ways to intuitively inform the user that they should tap to add an image.

Comment: do u mean as a badge?

Comment: if a badge works better then sure

Comment: do u mean another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to understand the question. Allowing users to reassign images in the right hand column via the Symbole dialog is fine. However I would go to a separate form for new categories where users can select icons as well as enter the new category name. It is more work, but improves your ux.

Comment: ok, but i want also, that the use could change an existing image...

Comment: Since this looks like an iPhone implementation which may have to run on a very small screen, I would leave it to the user to "discover" that they are able to change these icons. Your priority should be to give them an obvious choice initially when they create new categories. And for that I would suggest the new form with text field and icon grid. You can re-use your collection view in it.


FYI: UI = user interface, UX = user experience

Answer (score 1):

It's UX question (question about user experience of app using), but it's refers to question "how user should understand that he can select image for this row". In my opinion you should use add sign, something like this:

[image]

But if there enough space you could also add button with title "add" in editing state (problems will appear with localisation).

Comment: sorry, don´t know what´s an **UX question**